# How to add a string value to the front of viewbag SQL query list

Tags: sql, list, asp.net-core, viewbag

How do I get my `"ALL"` at the top of the list?

When I use `.Insert(0, "ALL")` it doesn't work either.

CODE:

```
// Category
var CategoryFilter = (from r in _context.INT_CertificationCategories select r.Category).Distinct().ToList();
CategoryFilter.Add("ALL");
ViewBag.CategoryList = CategoryFilter;
```

Comment: It may help if you share how this list is used on View. If you try to change order of elements in UI web control (combobox, list, ..), check whether that control has any custom sorting logic, that may ignore the order of elements in `CategoryList `. Otherwise `.Insert(0, "ALL")` should work for you...

Comment: I was using the `.Insert` on the viewbag and not the Filter like a dummy. SMH -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
CategoryFilter.Insert(0,"ALL")
```